# ASP.NET HTTPS for specific directory

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https

One question, Lets say that I have an Admin directory on my webpage and I want to use HTTPS for every page in the directory, what is the best way to achieve this ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the IIS instance, a quick way to do this is to edit the Properties of your admin folder, go to Directory Security, under Secure Communications, click on Edit... and Check require secure channel (SSL).

This disallows any http traffic altogether, and doesn't handle a redirect as you could do in  your code.

[image]

Comment: And what if I don't have access to the IIS ?

Comment: I do something exactly like what @Porco suggests in his answer: if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("https://SECURESERVER.COM" + Request.RawUrl.ToString(), true);
                        }

Comment: So if I have a page like http://aaa.com/index.aspx i would use Response.Redirect("https://aaa.com/index.aspx"); ?? I don't get it

Comment: No, you would say if( !Request.IsSecureConnection ) { Response.Redirect("h t t p s:// aaa .com/index.aspx", true ); } Without all the spaces obviously. SE's link code messed up my initial comment, i didn't notice.

Comment: No problem. If you go that route though, you should select Porco's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

For the Admin directory you could add a Request.IsSecureConnection check and if that returns false redirect them to the same page with https.